# Step-by-step help using the distributive law in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need to prove the following set identity but I'm confused as to how to apply the set identities.

$\left(A\cup C\right)\cap[\left(A\cap B\right)\cup\left(C'\cap B\right)]=A\cap B$

I tried doing the first step of distribution but the problem got larger and larger, and then smaller, and now almost 10 steps later it seems to be growing again.  This makes me think I'm doing something really wrong.

Here is my first step:

$[(A \cup C)\cap A] \cup [(A \cup C) \cap B] \cup [(A \cup C) \cap C'] \cup [(A\cup C)\cap B]$

Is this first step of distribution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1_{\left(A\cup C\right)\cap\left[\left(A\cap B\right)\cup\left(C'\cap B\right)\right]}=1_{A\cup C}1_{\left(A\cap B\right)\cup\left(C'\cap B\right)}=$$$$\left(1_{A}+1_{C}-1_{A}1_{C}\right)\left(1_{A\cap B}+1_{C'\cap B}-1_{A\cap B}1_{C'\cap B}\right)=$$

$$\left(1_{A}+1_{C}-1_{A}1_{C}\right)\left(1_{A}1_{B}+1_{C'}1_{B}-1_{A}1_{B}1_{C'}1_{B}\right)$$

$$\left(1_{A}+1_{C}-1_{A}1_{C}\right)\left(1_{A}1_{B}+\left(1-1_{C}\right)1_{B}-1_{A}1_{B}\left(1-1_{C}\right)1_{B}\right)$$

If you work this out then you end up with:

$$\cdots=1_{A}1_{B}=1_{A\cap B}$$

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind intersections are associative.

In the square brackets, treat $(A \cap B)$ as one set, and $(C' \cap B)$ as another set. The first step should be
$$
\big(\underbrace{(A \cup C) \cap (A \cap B)}_C\big) \cup \big(\underbrace{(A \cup C) \cap (C' \cap B)}_D\big).
$$
For the first chunk $C$, we can distribute it as
$$
C = (A \cup C) \cap (A \cap B) = \big(\underbrace{(A \cup C) \cap A}_A\big) \cap \big((A \cup C) \cap B\big).
$$
This is $\big(A \cap (A \cup C)\big) \cap B = A \cap B$.

For the second chunk $D$, we do something similar, and find that $D = A \cap B \cap C'$ (you fill in details).

> This is because
> $$
> D = \big((A \cup C) \cap C'\big) \cap \big((A \cup C) \cap B\big).
> $$
> The first chunk of this is $(A \cap C') \cup (C \cap C') = A \cap C'$. Then
> $$
> D= \big(A \cap (A \cup C)\big) \cap C' \cap B = A \cap B \cap C'.
> $$

So the original set is
$$
(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B \cap C') = A \cap B.
$$

Comment: The rules seem to show some changing from $\cap$ to $\cup$ and yours application looks like general algebra.

Comment: Oh never mind, I think I see how you applied it by treating them as one set..